# unqualified ID error - c++

Tags: c++

Can anyone point out the error in the code?

```
73        POINT N;
74        N.x = (int) 1 - t * p1.X + t * p2.X;
75        N.y = (int) ((1 - t) * p1.Y + t * p2.Y);
76
77        return N;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
||=== Build: Debug in tester (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\CodeBlocks\openGL workspace\tester\main.cpp||In member function 'POINT drawDeCasteljau::getCasteljauPoint(int, int, double)':|
C:\CodeBlocks\openGL workspace\tester\main.cpp|74|error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant|
C:\CodeBlocks\openGL workspace\tester\main.cpp|74|error: expected ';' before numeric constant|
C:\CodeBlocks\openGL workspace\tester\main.cpp|75|error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant|
C:\CodeBlocks\openGL workspace\tester\main.cpp|75|error: expected ')' before numeric constant|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I saw a few posts with same error.. but none I saw helped debugging it.

Comment: What about putting a pair of braces around the expression? Like `(int) (1 - t * p1.X + t * p2.X);`

Comment: Also, post full, compilable code. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for an explanation of why. We can't help you with nothing but 3 lines.

Comment: Are you sure it is not `p1.x`? C++ is case-sensitive...

Comment: the problem got solved. Next will be more careful to post as much as details as possible Stefano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough information that to make an exact conclusion. But it seems that data members x and y either shall be in upper case that is X and Y or both in low case that is x and y for all variables N, p1 and p2 that as I think have type POINT..

Comment: i was messing up with the cases of variable.. thank you for pointing out.. :)